# HTML5 local storage not saving between page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am using HTML5 local storage for the first time using FF5. I have the below javascript, it should save a string into local storage, however when the page is reloaded there isn't any values in local storage. What am I doing wrong? Why is 'foo' not populated on the pages sedond load?

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

if (!localStorage) {return false; }

var foo = localStorage.getItem("key1");

if (foo != null)
{
   document.getByName("identifier").value = foo;
}

localStorage["key1"] = "value1";

});
</script>
```

Comment: You sure it's not breaking or something?  That code ought to work.  Did you check in Firebug to see what the localStorage contents are?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `localStorage.setItem`. For example

```
localStorage.setItem("key1", "value1");
```

NOTE: IE 7 does not have localStorage support

Answer (score 3):

I've also had this same issue. I've discovered that I am unable to retrieve items from local storage during the document.ready, but I am able to get the items afterwards.

Comment: Sorry for making this an answer, I don't have enough points to add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the "setItem" method, i.e.:

```
localStorage.setItem('key1', 'value1');
```

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

     if (!localStorage) {return false; }

    var foo = localStorage.getItem("key1");

    if (foo == null)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('key1', 'value1');
    }

    alert(localStorage.getItem("key1"));


    });
    </script>

Comment: Hi

I tried that but it still didn't work. I'm not sure why. The below script will always go in the if (foo == null) statement (foo is always null). Any ideas? Thanks 

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

     if (!localStorage) {return false; }

     var foo = localStorage.getItem("key1");

     if (foo == null)
     {
     localStorage.setItem('key1', 'value1');
     }

     alert(localStorage.getItem("key1"));

     });
     </script>

Comment: Your code worked for me without making any modifications. What browser are you using?

Comment: Just FYI: your alert statement is outside the foo == null logic, so it will always execute.

Comment: I sort of have it working now. With HTML5 local storage should the state be maintained if I close the browser then reload it and go to the same page? With the above code that you tried what did you see?

Thank you Ben

Comment: The key value pair will be maintained. localStorage.getItem("key1") will equal value1 when the page is reloaded. It will remain that way until you use the clear() method to remove it programmatically, or you manually clear it from your browser.

Comment: BTW, http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html is a great overview of localStorage. I highly recommend reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my code

You do not need getItem and setItem

```
jQuery('.close-intro').click(function() {
    window.localStorage['intro'] = 1;
    jQuery('.intro-holder').slideUp();
    jQuery('.open-intro').show();
});
jQuery('.open-intro').click(function() {
    window.localStorage['intro'] = 0;
    jQuery('.intro-holder').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).hide();
});
var opcl = window.localStorage['intro'];
if (opcl == 1) {
    jQuery('.intro-holder').slideUp();
    jQuery('.open-intro').show();
}
if (opcl == 0) {
    jQuery('.intro-holder').slideDown();
    jQuery('.open-intro').hide();
}
```